# How to create a dynamic body in Box2D?

Tags: android

I am totally new to Box2D in Android.
I am trying to create a body in ANDROID, but it never seems to work.
I imported the library to the lib folder.
And I tried somthing like this.

```
            BodyDef bodyDef  = new BodyDef();
        Vec2 initVel = new Vec2();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();



                bodyDef.position.set(3.303636f, 7.712577f);
            bodyDef.userData = block1;
            bodyDef.angle = 0.000000f;
            Body rectangle = world.createBody(bodyDef);
            initVel.set(0.000000f, 0.000000f);
            rectangle.setLinearVelocity(initVel);
            rectangle.setAngularVelocity(0.000000f);

            Vec2[] rectangle_vertices = new Vec2[4];
            rectangle_vertices[0].set(-0.921088f, -0.614059f);
            rectangle_vertices[1].set(0.921088f, -0.614059f);
            rectangle_vertices[2].set(0.921088f, 0.614059f);
            rectangle_vertices[3].set(-0.921088f, 0.614059f);

            shape.set(rectangle_vertices, 4);
            fd.shape = shape;
            fd.density = 0.015000f;
            fd.friction = 0.300000f;
            fd.restitution = 0.600000f;
            rectangle.createFixture(fd);
```

can anyone help me on this.
Or PLease provide me with a sample code or how to start with Box2D.
My main problem was some of the things like "FixtureDef" was not imported.
Actually I tried to port the code which I used in Iphone Box2D to android.

Please anyone help.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this URL tutorial](http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/) first!

Have a look at [this code](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CFcQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fandengineexamples.googlecode.com%2Fhg%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fanddev%2Fandengine%2Fexamples%2FPhysicsExample.java%3Fr%3D6c56d06c146e78624acce90dcd76f079279e667d&ei=5BE8TdfHF8XUrQeIxoDoCA&usg=AFQjCNHRneLPUYpISp7d6CnVjoHL4GRqXg&sig2=hnz7wiUV9tIys6IzJlT9iw) as well!

Hope these would be useful..

Comment: Thankyou for the help.But I am getting "force close" on it. can you give me  a working sample code of creating one bodies with fixtures, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing with `Box2d` in Android I would recommend you to check the cocos2d ports.

- [Java version](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/)
- [C++ version](http://www.cocos2d-x.com/)